# Cypress - Aliases : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'todoItem')

Tags: cypress, alias

I'm using [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) and I have an error when I try to access to "todoItem" text in the `"expect(this.todoItem).to.eq('New Todo')"` line.

Any ideas on how to access the "todoItem" text?

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.get(".new-todo").type("New Todo {Enter}");
  cy.get(".todo-list>li:nth-child(1)").invoke("text").as("todoItem");
});

it("gets added todo item", () => {
  expect(this.todoItem).to.eq("New Todo");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reference a Cypress alias using `this`, [you need to use a regular function instead of an arrow function](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Avoiding-the-use-of-this).

```js
it('gets added todo item', function () {
  expect(this.todoItem).to.eq('New Todo');
});
```

You can also reference the alias by using `cy.get()`. This may be advantageous in situations where you want the alias to be used asynchronously in the Cypress command chain.

```js
it('gets added todo item', () => {
  cy.get('@todoItem').should('equal', 'New Todo');
});
```